# jQuery Validation plugin individual validation of field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with following fields:

1. User name
2. login id
3. password
4. confirm password
5. tags

   > ```
   > $(function () {
   >     $("#myForm").validate({
   >         rules: {
   >             user_name: "required",
   >             login_id: {
   >                 required: true,
   >                 minlength: 2
   >             },
   >             password: {
   >                 required: true,
   >                 minlength: 5
   >             },
   >             confirm_password: {
   >                 required: true,
   >                 minlength: 5,
   >                 equalTo: "#password"
   >             },
   >             experience: {
   >                 required: true,
   >                 regex: '/^[0-9]{2}$/'
   >             },
   >               tag_name: {
   >                         required: true
   >                 }  
   >
   >         }
   > });
   > ```

In the above code tags is not mandatory but i want to validate tags field at the time of an event (button) individually, So how can I make rules for this individual field tag in jquery validation plugin.

To be more specific, I have one field tags and one button inside myForm, tags field is non mandatory for the form but if you put something in tag field and then click this particular button then in that case I have to validate tags field. I guess I have made my point.

Question: How can I add validation rule using jQuery validator in the above case?

Comment: Call `.valid()` on the element.

Comment: @Barmar where should I add rule?

Comment: You add the rule to the `rules:` option. If it's not mandatory, just leave out `required: true`.

Comment: @Balmer I have added rule in rules and now it is a part of form! It doesn't help...Any comment?

Comment: Add an update to the question that shows what you've tried.

Comment: i thought you didn't want it to be required.

Comment: At the time of form validation it is not required but on some event I want to validate it using plugin.

Comment: You can't have it both ways. If you make it required in the options, it will be required at the time of form validation. I thought you just wanted to check the format of it when they click the button.